# Copy/paste values and formats while asking for name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy over all of the values and formats to a different spreadsheet, week by week, creating a new sheet within the workbook each time. This is for archival purposes. I have pieced together the following:

```
function ArchiveByWeek(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CRS Stats By Week')
  var buildVersion = Browser.inputBox("What is the Weekend Ending Date?");
  var sValues = source.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sBG = source.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  var sFC = source.getDataRange().getFontColors();
  var sFF = source.getDataRange().getFontFamilies();
  var sFL = source.getDataRange().getFontLines();
  var sFFa = source.getDataRange().getFontFamilies();
  var sFSz = source.getDataRange().getFontSizes();
  var sFSt = source.getDataRange().getFontStyles();
  var sFW = source.getDataRange().getFontWeights();
  var sHA = source.getDataRange().getHorizontalAlignments();
  var sVA = source.getDataRange().getVerticalAlignments();
  var sNF = source.getDataRange().getNumberFormats();
  var sWR = source.getDataRange().getWraps();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WVfJGDbdOewO2H-aMhQiek7sCOolK6xH7cSbfZ8KQgY');
  var destinationSheet = destination.insertSheet(buildVersion, 1);
  destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues)
  .setBackgrounds(sBG)
  .setFontColors(sFC)
  .setFontFamilies(sFF)
  .setFontLines(sFL)
  .setFontFamilies(sFFa)
  .setFontSizes(sFSz)
  .setFontStyles(sFSt)
  .setFontWeights(sFW)
  .setHorizontalAlignments(sHA)
  .setVerticalAlignments(sVA)
  .setNumberFormats(sNF)
  .setWraps(sWR);
}
```

This seems to work fine, only some cells are not copied. For some reason, it is only cells that are summing other cells. Can't figure out why.

I found the following script, which worked perfectly, only I was unable to find a way to give each new sheet a unique name:

```
function copySheetValues(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sourcename = source.getSheetName();
  var sValues = source.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sBG = source.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  var sFC = source.getDataRange().getFontColors();
  var sFF = source.getDataRange().getFontFamilies();
  var sFL = source.getDataRange().getFontLines();
  var sFFa = source.getDataRange().getFontFamilies();
  var sFSz = source.getDataRange().getFontSizes();
  var sFSt = source.getDataRange().getFontStyles();
  var sFW = source.getDataRange().getFontWeights();
  var sHA = source.getDataRange().getHorizontalAlignments();
  var sVA = source.getDataRange().getVerticalAlignments();
  var sNF = source.getDataRange().getNumberFormats();
  var sWR = source.getDataRange().getWraps();

  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15ucPbZrIYXZAOCYVdpK6OA0oyQT1NcsmuiJmDRfdpHQ');
  var destinationSheet = destination.insertSheet(sourcename, 0);
  destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues)
  .setBackgrounds(sBG)
  .setFontColors(sFC)
  .setFontFamilies(sFF)
  .setFontLines(sFL)
  .setFontFamilies(sFFa)
  .setFontSizes(sFSz)
  .setFontStyles(sFSt)
  .setFontWeights(sFW)
  .setHorizontalAlignments(sHA)
  .setVerticalAlignments(sVA)
  .setNumberFormats(sNF)
  .setWraps(sWR);
}
```

Comment: Because you are not asking the user? What part of the script exactly isn't working?

Comment: on another note you should reduce all those getDataRange() calls, something like var range = source.getDataRange(); var sValues = range.getValues(); var sBG = range.getBackgrounds(); etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to come up with a solution that I was satisfied with. This was able to paste all of the values, and formats exactly as they were on the sheet when viewing. It asks for a name of the new sheet, which was my intention:

```
    function Archive() {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET NAME')
    var sValues = source.getDataRange()
        .getValues();
    var weekEnding = Browser.inputBox("What is the Weekend Ending Date?");
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET ID');
    var copy = source.copyTo(destination)
        .setName(weekEnding)
    copy.getRange(1, 1, sValues.length, sValues[0].length)
        .setValues(sValues); // overwrite all formulas that the copyTo preserved
```